# Mocking a required class without actually importing it in Jest test

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Using Jest example, the required class

```
// sound-player.js
export default class SoundPlayer {
  constructor() {    
    // do something
  }
}
```

and the class being tested:

```
// sound-player-consumer.js
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';

export default class SoundPlayerConsumer {
  playSomethingCool() {
    this.soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
  }
}
```

I want to test if `SoundPlayerConsumer` ever called (created an object of)  `SoundPlayer` on `playSomethingCool()`. My understanding, it will look something like this:

```
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';
import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer';
jest.mock('./sound-player');

beforeEach(() => {
  SoundPlayer.mockClear();
});

it('check if the consumer is called', () => {
  const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
  soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool();
  expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

However, in my case I don't want to import `./sound-player` as it has many requirements and dependencies which is an overkill for my test, thus I just want to manually mock the class.
Here's what I tried so far:

```
  import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer'; 
  const SoundPlayer = jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
    return function() {
      return {}
    }
  });
  it('check if the consumer is called', () => {
    const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
    soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool();
    expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

but this is the result I get `Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function` I have tried a couple other variations but I always ended up with the same result.

I have read into [Jest Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks), but couldn't fully grasp it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn), `mockImplementation` can be used to mock class constructors. Thus, you may mock a class and return jest function using `mockImplementation`.

```
  import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer';

  // must have a 'mock' prefix
  const mockSoundPlayer = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {}
  });

  const SoundPlayer = jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
    return mockSoundPlayer
  });

  it('check if the consumer is called', () => {
    const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer();
    soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool();
    expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this for a non-local module with a default export. Trying to adapt your answer the obvious way doesn't work; do you have any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

[Per the Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), what you want to do is not possible:

> Modules that are mocked with jest.mock are mocked only for the file that calls jest.mock. Another file that imports the module will get the original implementation even if it runs after the test file that mocks the module.

So you're left with various kinds of dependency injection or other refactors. One option might be:

```
// sound-player-consumer.js
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';

export default class SoundPlayerConsumer {
  constructor({soundPlayer: Soundplayer}) {
    this.soundPlayer = new soundPlayer();
  }
  playSomethingCool(/* or you could inject SoundPlayer here */) {
    // etc
  }
}
```

And then in your tests, you can build a fake `SoundPlayer` and pass it in and test it as you like.

```
  import SoundPlayerConsumer from './sound-player-consumer'; 
  class FakeSoundPlayer {}
  it('check if the consumer is called', () => {
    const soundPlayerConsumer = new SoundPlayerConsumer({soundPlayer: FakeSoundPlayer});
    soundPlayerConsumer.playSomethingCool();
    expect(SoundPlayer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```